# Ethereum remix web3 connection problem

Tags: remix, json-rpc, nodes, web3j, ide

I tried to connect to an ethereum node by using [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org). It means that I am using http and not https. However, I receive same error message:

```
Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).
```

Is there any other solution for this problem ? I searched in internet and found only one answer : use of http, that in my  case I receive same error message.

Comment: are you trying to connect to a local node?

Comment: @Achala Dissanayake No, how can do this? thanks

Comment: @ Achala Dissanayake i receive same message yet. this is not because of geth (go ethereum) ? since i have not installed it yet

Comment: you need to have a node running locally, either using geth or any other way. Not having a local node gives you the error. try installing geth running a local node with `-rpc` flag, this will solve your error

Comment: Did you get it solved?

Comment: @Ethfanatic yes before connection restrpc must be run.

Comment: Its better if you can accept an answer, I think answer is there, telling to open an rpc port

Comment: please help me, I run rpc on my console, from http://remix.ethereum.org, I check rpc port and everything, but I received same error message about web3 provider from solidity browser, thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24073)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remix provide you with three environments to run your smart contract code. As well explained in the [docs](http://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run_tab.html),

> 1. JavaScript VM: All the transactions will be executed in a sandbox blockchain in the browser. This means nothing will be persisted and a
>      page reload will restart a new blockchain from scratch, the old one
>      will not be saved.
> 2. Injected Provider: Remix will connect to an injected web3 provider. Mist and Metamask are example of providers that inject web3, thus can
>      be used with this option.
> 3. Web3 Provider: Remix will connect to a remote node. You will need to provide the URL address to the selected provider: geth, parity or
>      any Ethereum client.

As a beginner it will be better to use JavaScriptVM as it's convenient because each execution runs in your browser and no external tool, node is needed . Reloading the page will restart Remix with an empty state.

If you want the code run in a actual node, either you should run your own node and open a rpc endpoint (in geth using `--rpc` flag) and provide the url for the endpoint after selecting *Web3 Provider* option as environment in run tab

or

use injected web3. E.g. have metamask extension installed in your browser and create an account and select a network (Ethereum main net or any other testnet.)

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. Just you please tell me how can I use JavaScriptVM to connect to a local node ? thanks a lot

Comment: JSVM is run in your browser and uses a sandbox blockchain, it can't be used to connect to a local node. If you want to connect to a local node, set environment to web3 provider and provide the rpc endpoint url of your local node ( when running a local node with geth by default it is `http://localhost:8545`). is it clear?

Comment: @  Achala Dissanayake exactly this is what I am trying to do. However, as I explained above, I receive that error message, even when I use http instead of https. I though may it is because of npm and node.js but after installation I receive same message

Comment: have you opened a rpc end point? are you using geth?

Comment: @ Achala Dissanayake no i amusing only http://remix.ethereum.org. how can i open an rpc ?

Comment: if you want to connect to a local node, you need to have a local node running with rpc end point opened even with remix. easiest way is using geth. find instructions [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth). you can either connect to main net or try your own [private blockchain](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster). hope it is clear?

Answer (score 3):

> Web3 Provider: Remix will connect to a remote node. You will need to
>   provide the URL address to the selected provider: geth, parity or any
>   Ethereum client

To provide a URL you need to have a node running somewhere. To use `http://localhost:8545`, you need to have a local node running and port `8545` opened to it via JSON RPC.

As explained in the other answer's comments by @AchalaDissanayake you can simply do it with Geth, and there are many other as well.

Comment: Would you please say that how to Would you please say that how to "have a local node running" and how to be sure that "port 8545 opened to it via JSON RPC" ?

Comment: I just went thru the other answer and its comments. Looks like everything is there. Hope you got it well explained  :)

Comment: @ETHER Thank you very much for the bounty